# php warning fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given

Tags: php, file-io, warnings

I use newrelic to keep track of anything on my website and I always get this error:

> Error message: E_WARNING: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   Stack trace: in fclose called at /etc/snmp/bfd-stats.php (68)

This is how `/etc/snmp/bfd-stats.php` looks like

```
<?php

$a = 0;
$ptr = 0;
$any = 0;
$mx = 0;
$ns = 0;
$cname = 0;
$soa = 0;
$srv = 0;
$aaaa = 0;
$txt = 0;
$total = 0;

if(file_exists('/etc/snmp/bfd-log-pos.stat')) {
    $lfh = fopen('/etc/snmp/bfd-log-pos.stat','r');
    $string = fread($lfh,2087);
    $res = explode(',',$string);
    fclose($lfh);
}
else {
    $res = array();
    $res[0] = 0;
    $res[1] = 0;
}

if(file_exists("/var/log/bfd_log.1")) {
    $stats = stat('/var/log/bfd_log.1');
    if($stats[10] > $res[0]) {
        $res[0] = 0;
        $res[1] = 0;
    }
}

$fh = fopen('/var/log/bfd_log', 'r');

fseek($fh,$res[1]);

$blocks = 0;

if(!$fh) {
    echo "Error! Couldn't open the file.";
} else {
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $data = fgets($fh);
        if(preg_match('/executed\sban/',$data)) {
            $blocks++;
        }
    }
}

$lfh = fopen('/etc/snmp/bfd-log-pos.stat','w');

$timestamp = time();
$pos = ftell($fh);
fwrite($lfh,"$timestamp,$pos");
fclose($lfh);

if(!fclose($fh)) {
    echo "Error! Couldn't close the file.";
} 

print("bfd_blocks\n$blocks");

?>
```

On line 40: `$fh = fopen('/var/log/bfd_log', 'r');` I looked at the directory `/var/log` and there is no file called `bfd_log`, I dont know if I have to create it by myself or it is automatically created.

Can anyone help me on fixing this error, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fopen` may return `false`. So you have to check `$lfh` and `$fh` are not `false` before `fclose()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you are trying to pass a variable with a boolean value (true/false) to a function that needs a resource instead of a boolean value.

Please make sure that before you use resources from variables, the function that returns the resource has not run into trouble. Only on success perform the other functions that use this resource/variable.

```
$fh = fopen('/var/log/bfd_log', 'r');
// check fh before other functions use this variable
if (!$fh) {
    echo "Error! Couldn't open the file.";
} else {

    // perform task with resource $fh
    fseek($fh, $res[1]);
    [...]

    $lfh = fopen('/etc/snmp/bfd-log-pos.stat', 'w');

    // check before other code block is executed and use this variable
    if( $lfh )
    {

        // perform task with resource $lfh
        $pos = ftell($fh);
        fwrite($lfh, "$timestamp,$pos");
        fclose($lfh);
        fclose($fh);

       [...]

    } else {
        // lfh error   
    }
}
```

If you always check before using variables, you won't run into this error anymore.

Comment: I added `if($fh)` before the `fclose()` function but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: post your complete code the error message indicates to a line that is higher then your code above

Comment: Thank you @ins0, You were right i tried to make sure if every variable is good to go before using it. Now every thing seems good, and i am having this obvious problem E_WARNING: fopen(/var/log/bfd_log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory; Do you think i have to create the file myself or force it to be created(but remember `$lfh = fopen('/etc/snmp/bfd-log-pos.stat','r');` initially we open it just to read information)

Comment: it depends on the task you are trying to solve, if you don't want to create files that not exists by ``fopen`` use the ``file_exists`` function before try to read a file ``if(file_exists..) { //do fopen etc }`` may accept this as your answer if this was you looking for your question

Comment: Thanks! @insO, you are a life saver. Finally what do you suggest about creating the file manually as you can see its system log file.

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this problem and could not find the answer until I separated my write check (put it first) from the actual file write code.  So before I would open the file fopen/fwrite then do the is_writable check and then do the fclose and i would get this error.
To resolve I moved the is_writable and variable declaration before the fopen/fwrite and the error went away.  Shown below (former php code position shown in comments) The first comment did help me realize this...  Thank you.

```
$myfile = "/var/www/html/newfile.txt";

if (is_writable($myfile))  {
  echo  "The file is writable";
}
else {
  echo "The file is not writable";
}

$txt = "$name, $email, $command, $searchtype,  $keyword \n";
$myfile = fopen('/var/www/html/newfile.txt', 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

// $myfile = "/var/www/html/newfile.txt";

// if (is_writable($myfile))  {
//  echo  "The file is writable";
// }
// else {
//   echo "The file is not writable";
// }

fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$fh = fopen('/var/log/bfd_log', 'a+');
```

a+ mode will create the file if it does not exists