# php warning fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.org/home/DDL/download.php on line 60

Tags: php, download, resources, warnings, fclose

I picked up and modified a PHP download code, but I always get this error:

> **Warning:** fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.org/home/DDL/download.php on line 60

Where obviously "www.mysite.org" is changed with my site url.

I searched in the other questions, but there were only similar problems, not identical, with different cases.

The script is this one:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$path = "/DDL/FILES/";

$dl_file = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).]|[\.]{2,})", '', $_GET['download_file']);
$dl_file2 = filter_var($dl_file, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$fullPath = $path.$dl_file2;

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "zip":
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "mkv-video":
        header("Content-type: video/x-matroska");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "mp4-video":
        header("Content-type: video/mp4");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "aac":
        header("Content-type: audio/aac");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "flac":
        header("Content-type: audio/x-flac");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
        case "mp3":
        header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;

        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        break;
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
ob_clean();
    flush();
fclose ($fd);
} else {
    echo 'something wrong with the file?';
}
exit;
```

I made some researches and talked with some people, and we arrived at the conclusion that it could be a DB error, because everything we tried didn't solve the problem.

Can anyone help me on fixing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fopen` returns a false if it fails, so none of your `if` statement will be run; however, you're always trying to close the file - you don't need to do that if it's not actually open, so you can move the `fopen` line to inside your if statement.

Comment: thanks, I did the changes, but now it gives me a syntax error `unexpected '$fsize' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: Could you update the code in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php warning fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032923/php-warning-fclose-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the following string:

```
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
```

"What is wrong with it?" you might ask. Well, if `fopen` returns `FALSE`, your expression is not evaluated and you end up with the execution skipping right to

```
ob_clean();
flush();
fclose ($fd);
```

And since `$fd` is not defined in this scope... You should have guessed it by now.

Move your code after `if` statement inside the `if` statement:

```
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    // the rest of the code that could have been cropped
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    fclose ($fd);
} else {
    echo 'something wrong with the file?';
}
exit;
```

Comment: I did the changes. Since `fopen` returns `false`, it gives me a warning  `fopen(/DDL/FILES/test.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web/htdocs/www.mysite.org/home/DDL/download.php on line 12`. But the file is there.

Comment: well, the problem is not the script, it could be your permissions, your web server is chrooted or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try asking support from my web server provider.

Answer (score 1):

try something more simple like below:

```
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) { 
  fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");   
  fclose($fd); 
}
```

then try to integrate it into your script.