# Download file from url to directory

Tags: php

Tried searching with downloading file. I couldn't find the required answer. I'm trying to download the file from url to a specific directory/folder in php. I'm using the code below.

```
foreach($files as $file) {

     $url  = 'http://www.example.com/'.$file.'';
     $path = '/project/'.$file.'';

     $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

     if($fp) {         
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

     $data = curl_exec($ch);

     curl_close($ch);
     fclose($fp);       
  }
}
```

When I run php file. It displays the errors:

```
Warning: fopen(/project/GEN1.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in.

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php warning fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032923/php-warning-fclose-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

Comment: I tried with the parameters, still I couldn't download the file.

Comment: Are you sure the file is present at `/project/GEN1.mp4`? Add an `if` statement to check the `fp`, you execute the other line into the `if`so you are sure the file is open.

Comment: Yes the file exists and I tested the url, file download was done.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
foreach($files as $file) {

     $url  = 'http://www.example.com/'.$file.'';
     $path = '/project/'.$file.'';

     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

     $data = curl_exec($ch);

     curl_close($ch);

     $fp = fopen($path, 'wb');
     fwrite($fp, $data);
     fclose($fp);
}
```

- The error `Warning: fopen(/project/GEN1.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.` is telling you that the file don't exist, so you need to create it manually or with the `fopen` call, take a look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for the possible modes.
- The error `Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`  means that you are passing a boolean variable to the `fclose` function that require a resource.
- The error `Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in.` means that you need to pass a FileHandle to the function.

Comment: Carlo Zanocco, I tried the code. The file is downloaded a copy to specific folder. But when I play the video file. it was not working (VLC is unable to open the file(/..../)

Comment: What do you mean with `(VLC is unable to open the file(/..../)`? Can you check the size of the file, it should be > 0 Kb

Comment: The filesize is 0 bytes.

Comment: I guess curl is cleaning the file content.

Comment: Can you try to download the file manually and verify if it works correctly?

Comment: Could you kindly check the code once. The downloaded file from url is saved with 0bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221164/discussion-between-carlo-zanocco-and-corren).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another PHP function `file_get_contents` instead of CURL. More information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)